# generic tunnel utility though a single tcp connection?

Tags: linux, debian, tunnel

I have a embedded Linux device (in it's own private LAN connected to other sensoric devices) that's connected to the Internet. I can already make a secure, direct TCP connection using a proprietary protocol between my computer and the device. That by itself is already a tunnel and I can, for example, connect to SSH daemon on the device (via the tunnel).

Now I'd like to run another tunnel over that TCP connection that gives me more possibilities. Specifically:

- has a **Linux** tunnel endpoint, that gets installed on the device
- has a *userfriendly* (read: really easy to use) **Windows** program acting as the local tunnel entry point and and allows the user to configure the desired tunnel parameters (destination point and IP addresses)
- allows multiple tunnels over one **single TCP connection** (important, as establishing that connection is relatively slow)
- preferably supports **FTP** connections (which won't work if not specifically supported)
- does not *require* any kind of authentification (so ssh-tunnels unfortunately can't be used)

Of course I tried to find such a software by googling around, but could not find anything usable...

Pratically, something like this:

```
  (USER PC) 

+---------+   +-----------+
|   FTP   |-->|           |
| client  |-->| Windows   |   +----------+
+---------+   |  tunnel   |   | existing |
              | server    |-->| tunnel   | ------------->>  INTERNET 
+---------+   |           |   | server   |
| browser |-->| (wanted)  |   +----------+
+---------+   +-----------+    localhost
                localhost

     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

                                            +-----------+
                             +----------+   | Linux     |--> l27.0.0.1:80
                             | existing |   |  tunnel   |
     INTERNET  >>------------| tunnel   |-->| client    |--> 192.168.0.1:21
                             | client   |   |           |
                             +----------+   | (wanted)  |--> 192.168.0.1:20 
                                            +-----------+
                                              localhost

                                                   (EMBEDDED DEVICE)
```

Does such a tool exist or do I really need to write it on my own?

Comment: A Virtual Private Network (VPN) is commonly used in such situations.

Comment: Yeah, but to allow access to other devices in the distant LAN I need to do bridging and AFAIK that involves lots of configuration (note that even if I have full software access (root) to the device at the moment, it is already installed a few hundred km from here).

Comment: Regarding authentication, is it impossible to just bundle the authentication password or private-key?

Comment: What do you mean with "bundle"? Anyway, yes, I could create an additional dummy Linux user account and use it's password (but it would be much better if no password or private key would be necessary).

Comment: What leads you to believe that a VPN cannot bridge?  It is pretty easy to bridge a connection with OpenVPN

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your proprietary VPN is already a true tunnel (be it layer 2 or 3)? If that is the case, what more do you want? Layer 2 access (in which case bridging is a must)? On the other hand, is your VPN transport layer only (e.g. you have to use SOCKS)? In other words, does it appear as a TUN/TAP device on the client or server?